# Order by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine the following MySQL table of orders:

```
id | name
1  | Mike
2  | Steve
3  | Janet
4  | Juliet
5  | Mike
6  | Jane
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

However, I'd like to "group" those by `name`, so that I have orders from the same person listed after one another, however, I cannot do ORDER BY `name`.

This is my desired output:

```
id | name
6  | Jane
5  | Mike
1  | Mike
4  | Juliet
3  | Janet
2  | Steve
```

What's the query for this output?

Comment: " I cannot do ORDER BY name". Why not?

Comment: @Nanne: Because I need the descending ID order, with the exception where the name isn't distinct.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this in `sql` then?

Comment: could provide more details?

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY name, id` that should sort first on name and then subsort all items with the same name on id.

Comment: I've edited the question title since you apparently don't want any kind of `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT y.id
     , y.name  
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
 GROUP 
    BY name
     , id 
 ORDER 
    BY MAX(x.id) DESC
     , id DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have special calculation to get their row position.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name, 
                    @ord := @ord + 1 ord
            FROM        
                    (
                        SELECT  MAX(ID) ID, NAME
                        FROM    TableName 
                        GROUP   BY Name
                    ) a, (SELECT @ord := 0) b
            ORDER   BY ID DESC
        ) b ON a.Name = b.Name
ORDER   BY b.ord, a.ID DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6eb9/7)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via double `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY name ASC, id DESC
```

Comment: This definitely does't solve the problem at hand. Read the question again, please.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez why not? It provides correct output (as you've described, at least: similar names will be in one 'group' due to first `ORDER` condition, and `id` will be descending due to second `ORDER` condition). If not, please, clarify what's wrong.

Comment: Because it orders by name ascending, not by id descending, as my desired output is.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez if you will order by id first, then your names will not be gathered into group. It's obviously you're not completely understanding what you want or you're explaining it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
ORDER BY field(NAME,'Mike','Jane') desc,
`ID` desc;
```

**[exactly as you asked](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6de27/7)**

Comment: But this requires him to know all the names beforehand which seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this query if you want to have something which is more generic SQL.

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM ( SELECT id, name, (SELECT MAX(id) from Table1 where name=t.name) AS max_id 
     FROM Table1 AS t 
     ORDER BY max_id DESC, id DESC) as x
```

Answer (score -1):

What about to use [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)?
You can group it by name and then order...